# RhinoMock 3.6.1 wrongly reporting method not invoked?

Tags: c#, .net, rhino-mocks

I have some 3-year old (poorly written) tests that uses RhinoMock 3.6. Today I upgraded to 3.6.1 and suddenly I got an ExpectationViolationException when running the tests.

The setup is:

```
var userid = user.Identifier;
UserRepository.
    Expect(x => x.GetUser(Arg.Is(userid), Arg.Is(long.MinValue), out Arg<bool>.Out(true).Dummy))
    .Return(user);
```

and the exception is

> Rhino.Mocks.Exceptions.ExpectationViolationException :
>   IUserRepository.GetUser(equal to 6a90efd1-a290-452a-a8ac-5b38377bc597,
>   equal to -9223372036854775808, anything); Expected #1, Actual #0.

I have of course checked the values for the `userid` and it is ok. Downgrading to 3.6 makes the test pass.

Does any one know what could cause this problem?

Comment: Do you have any method which is Expected #0, but Actual #1?

Comment: No, I don't. And as mentioned downgrading resolved the problem. What do you suspect?

Comment: Is `userid` a `GUID`, or a `string`?

Comment: It is a GUID and it Equals ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a couple of changes related to the way Rhino Mocks handles out and ref parameters in versions 3.6 and 3.6.1, so I would change the test approach to something like this:

```
var userid = user.Identifier;
UserRepository.Stub(x => x
      .GetUser(Arg.Is(userid), Arg.Is(long.MinValue), out myVar)
      .OutRef(valueForMyVar)
      .Return(user);
```

And if you really wanna make sure you're calling the method, you can use UserRepository.AssertWasCalled at the end of the test...

Comment: Thanks. Your example does cause another exception, apparently due to the mix of Arg.Is and "pure" out parameter. But introducing the 'OutRef' did solve my problem :)